# ANy way to make java class files in sync online

Tags: java, eclipse, synchronization

I am practicing java in Eclipse both in home and college.

Is there any way that when i co the coding the file save on some server and syc there and then when i go to college then again i can use same file

Comment: This is not a programming question. However, allow me to suggest dropbox (http://www.dropbox.com). Here's my invite link (http://db.tt/oON9gko) which gives you (and me) an extra 250MB.

Comment: Or you can setup an account at http://www.github.com

Comment: Good point, this is an excellent opportunity to learn about source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using a distributed version control system like [mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).  The advantages of mercurial and bitbucket are really easy setup and unlimited private repositories (github doesn't offer this) which is perfect for course work and you get your stuff backed up on the cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You need a revision control system. Take a look at the various plugins for Eclipse, like for example [git](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) or [svn](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) plugins.

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is [Revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), but you will need to install it in a server you have access from both college and home. Maybe your college can provide you with some space or you might start a personal project in google code or gitHub. :)

I find CollabNet SubVersion Edge pretty Straightforward and easy to configure.